# awk: two files are queried

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files

`file1`:

```
>string1<TAB>Name1
>string2<TAB>Name2
>string3<TAB>Name3
```

`file2`:

```
>string1<TAB>sequence1
>string2<TAB>sequence2
```

I want to use `awk` to compare column 1 of respective files. If both files share a column 1 value I want to print column 2 of file1 followed by column 2 of file2. For example, for the above files my expected output is:

```
Name1<TAB>sequence1
Name2<TAB>sequence2
```

this is my code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$1] = $1; next } $1 in a { print a[$2], $2 }' file1 file2 >out
```

But the only thing I get is an empty first columnsequence

where is the error here?

Comment: `a[$1] = $1` should be `a[$1] = $2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your assignment is not right.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS="\t"}
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} 
       $1 in a {print a[$1],$2}' file1 file2

Name1 sequence1
Name2 sequence2
```

Comment: yes that was it! although I need the `FS=OFS` because I have spaces in my name